# ubuntu based app, authorized credentials automatically on installation

Tags: passwords

Anki in particular used my google credentials to get synced without me actually typing them.

Chromium Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on LinuxMint 19

Shouldn't I be asked to enter my credentials? I installed the software (`sudo make install`) and it logged in automatically with my google credentials, those that I use on chromium.